# PHP to calculate from SQL after Uploading CSV data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have CSV to SQL upload page that adds a timestamp to all table rows for that upload. This code works:

```
//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
$count = 0;

//loop through the csv file and insert into database
do { 
    if ($count>=0) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO cain (fill_date, ndc, quantity, days_supply, mail_indicator, plan_paid, member_paid, dispensing_fee, compound_indicator, nabp, daw, formulary_indicator, member_id, unc_price, total_members, total_period_rebate) VALUES
            ('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."','".$data[4]."','".$data[5]."','".$data[6]."','".$data[7]."','".$data[8]."','".$data[9]."','".$data[10]."','".$data[11]."','".$data[12]."','".$data[13]."','".$data[14]."','".$data[15]."')");
    }
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")); 
//
```

I am trying to use php to calculate totals from MySQL data by the most recent upload ('timestamp'), either on this same page or another page. This is the code I've tried, and it doesn't work. If I am trying to use calculations from an entire group of data by the 'timestamp' that is the most recently updated data, how can I structure those queries?
I will only need to add/subtract/multiply/divide for each row and then sum all of those results.

```
{
$a= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(unc_price + dispensing_fee - plan_paid - member_paid) FROM cain WHERE timestamp = 'SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM cain'");
}
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: You are comparing timestamp to a string, not the result of that query. If you want to use a sub-query, wrap it in parenthesis, not quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
$a= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(unc_price + dispensing_fee - plan_paid - member_paid) FROM cain WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM cain')");
}
echo $a;
?>
```

you should be using parenthesis as above

Comment: That returned "Resource id #3" on the page. I want to return the total sum of the additions/subtractions on those rows.

Comment: are you sure that you have many rows with the maximum time stamp?

Comment: Yes, there will likely be 10-20 rows with that same timestamp after the CSV from which those rows are generated is uploaded.

Comment: try to manually input the date and check if the main query works fine, and if it works check if the subquery alone returns the proper date